# apply classes to objects with id between two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any simple way to apply class to all elements with id between two numbers:

for example: all spans witd ids between 1000 and 2000

I know that before html5 numbers as IDs werent a good idea

thanks for any help

Comment: Why not use a common class for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$( '#wrapper' ).find( 'span[id]' ).filter(function () {
    return +this.id > 1000 && +this.id < 2000;
}).addClass( 'yourClass' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q23xF/

`wrapper` is the DOM element which contains all your SPANs. You only search for SPANs with `id` attributes within that wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select them at once using a DOM selector, you'd need to filter them:

```
$("span[id]").each(function() {
    var id = parseInt(this.id, 10);
    if (id > 1000 && id < 2000)
        $(this).addClass("inrange");
});
```

or

```
$("span[id]").filter(function() {
    var id = parseInt(this.id, 10);
    return id > 1000 && id < 2000;
}).addClass("inrange");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").each(function(
 if(this.id>1000||this.id<2000){
  $(this).addClass("class");
     }

)}
```